# Nunit Test Suite Run From Script

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm using Nunit 3.12, and I'd like to run various subsets of my tests from a script. For example, I know Nunit supports various attributes, and I can run various classes using the test window in Visual Studio, or test playlists.

However, is it possible to specify a subset of tests via script and execute from command line? Nunit Console appears to be a console test runner, but it's not clear if it's intended for this kind of scripted use. In Python with Pytest, you can run [run pytest from a Python script](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code), and in Java, with Junit, you can run particular classes from a gradle job, or [on the command line with an argument file](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher-argument-files).

I'm wondering because I'd like to set up particular sets of tests to be run in a build pipeline -- run the smoke tests over every dev build, but run the longer regression tests over every qa build, for example. Mostly this could be split up by classes, but I do also have attributes currently decorating different test inputs, etc.

UPDATE #1:

I'm targeting .NET framework 4.6.1.

Comment: In order to give you a good answer, it's necessary to know whether you are targeting the .NET Framework or .NET Core. NUnit3-console has the capabilities you want, but it doesn't currently run tests for .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NUnit.ConsoleRunner` to accomplish this -- the console runner takes `.txt` file containing namespaces of test cases to run. You can create multiple `.txt` test list files to use as build parameter to run automation against different test lists.

For pipeline, you'll also need to do scripting to build your project and restore package references. I like to use `Cake`, a C# build scripting tool that integrates with NUnit3. Cake builds the project and runs tests directly from the commandline.

I have a generic Cake / NUnit3 build script on my [GitHub](https://github.com/harbourc/GenericNUnit3CakeBuild) that can serve as a starting point for you. You'll need to install `Cake` to get started and familiarize yourself with their documentation [here](https://cakebuild.net/docs/tutorials/getting-started). Hope this helps -- let me know if you have additional questions about this.